# Many to many relationship core data query for specific collection

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

[image]

```
public enum Ability: String {
  case newcomer = "Newcomer"
  case beginner = "Beginner"
  case intermediate = "Intermediate"
  case advanced = "Advanced"
}

public enum Group: String {
  case solo = "Solo"
  case duo = "Duo"
  case team = "Team"
}
```

I want to find all performances that match the following.

```
ability == "Beginner"
group == "Duo"
performers == "Jane Davies" && "Alice Evans"
```

[The documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097033/1951992) suggests that aggregate operations in core data are not supported, which is surprising. Questions like this have been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2328651/1951992) here and suggest the use of 'Any'.

To my understanding, 'Any' would return performances that include 'Jane' or 'Alice' or 'Jane & Alice' right? I just want performances that include both 'Jane & Alice'.

How would I write a predicate for this query?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to test against a string array or against an array of  (two) Performer objects?

Comment: Hi @MartinR I'm interested in both.

Comment: You already accepted an answer, so apparently the problem is solved. – I just wonder because that predicate would give all objects which include "Jane" **or** "Alice" as a performer, and does not honor the last name at all.

Comment: Your right @MartinR

Comment: Would you like to submit a solution @MartinR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a list of (distinct) *Performer* objects, the following predicate *should* work
to find all *Performance* objects which are related exactly to those
performers:

```
let perf1 = ... // Performer object for "Jane Davies"
let perf2 = ... // Performer object for "Alice Evans"
let list = [perf1, perf2]

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "performers.@count = %ld AND ALL performers in %@", list.count, list)
```

but apparently is doesn't. The workaround is to use a SUBQUERY:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "performers.@count = %ld AND SUBQUERY(performers, $p, $p in %@).@count = %ld",
      list.count, list, list.count)
```

Comment: This works "performers.@count = %ld AND ANY performers in %@" but this doesn't "performers.@count = %ld AND ALL performers in %@"

Comment: @robdashnash: That is strange, because the first one would match a performance with performers  = ["Jane Davies", "SomeOne Else"]

Comment: I agree. [error] error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x604000191b90> , Unsupported predicate group == "Duo" AND ability == "Newcomer" AND performers.@count == 2 AND ALL performers IN {<Performer: 0x60400028a410> (entity: Performer; id: 0xd000000000480004 <x-coredata://4D819F21-4A27-4E39-B0F6-1644422653D6/Performer/p18> ; data: <fault>), <Performer: 0x60400028a5f0> (entity: Performer; id: 0xd0000000004c0004 <x-coredata://4D819F21-4A27-4E39-B0F6-1644422653D6/Performer/p19> ; data: <fault>)} with userInfo of (null)

Comment: It looks like 'ALL' is not supported by core data https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097033/1951992 but here you can see dave de long suggests otherwise https://stackoverflow.com/a/4217889/1951992

Comment: Does this work?  `NSPredicate(format: "performers.@count = %ld AND SUBQUERY(performers, $p, $p in %@).@count = %ld", list.count, list, list.count)`

Comment: Looks like a bug, similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/19716571/1187415 or this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473445/1187415 – and SUBQUERY is a workaround.